# Unicornify Image links are not oneboxed in chat

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, unicorns

I discovered a serious bug in chat today: **Unicornify Image links are not boxed**.

I pasted in the following:

```
http://unicornify.appspot.com/avatar/d8d1d62f89cf41fb5ff7a06e1b5c22fb?s=128
```

Expecting this:

[image]

Instead I got this:

[image]

In case you're having trouble seeing it, I've highlighted the problem here:

[image]

Comment: This might be more an issue with unicornify, I think chat needs the correct MIME type to insert images automatically. As a workaround try putting `!` in front of the link.

Comment: @fab - [indeed!](http://i.imgur.com/T7lYV.png)

Comment: @Fabian I guess that will have to do for now...

Comment: +1 for purple unicorn!

Comment: Unicorns don't MIME, they...

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment SHINE?

Comment: Well they certainly don't `onebox`....

Comment: One does not simply onebox into unicorns

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We don't special case it, indeed (although maybe we could). Adding a leading `!` will (as Fabian notes) make sure it knows it is an image:

```
!http://unicornify.appspot.com/avatar/d8d1d62f89cf41fb5ff7a06e1b5c22fb?s=128
```

Other than that, we just try to recognise urls that are *likely* an image.

Comment: ... although maybe we, *ahem* should ;)

Comment: What's all this "could"/"should" talk? We *must* do this!

Comment: I will make do with using this logical NOT `!` sign while I'm NOT a unicorn, but when I become one again, **this has to change**.

Comment: **Or** an alternative would be appending `&ext=.jpg` to the URL.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison H4X